# Lucene.net: Trying to read the index with WildcardTermEnum for autosuggestion

Tags: .net, lucene

We are trying to read the Lucene-index in order to list index contents when someone is typing the search expression - e.g. when "bas" was entered we want to show a list of all index terms starting with "bas".

Lucene.dll is version 1.4.3.3 and we can't use a newer one because of our (old) application.

THe code ist

```
Dim index_reader as Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader
dim test_term as Lucene.Net.index.Term

index_reader.open("C:\\inetpub\\fulltextindex\" )

test_term = new Lucene.Net.index.Term  ("BAT:", "bas*" )

Dim results As  Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardTermEnum
results =  new Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardTermEnum(index_reader, test_term )
```

The last line throws an exception "Serverfehler in der Anwendung /.
Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt."

Any ideas?

Other access like this works

```
query_text = "BAT:world" ' Request.QueryString("query")
query = Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.Queryparser.Parse(query_text, "contents", analyzer)
hits = searcher.Search(query)
Response.Write(query_text & ": " & hits.Length.ToString())
```

**Problem is solved:**

This does not open the index (without error message)

```
index_reader.open("C:\\inetpub\\fulltextindex\" )
```

This opens the index and everything works fine

```
index_reader = index_reader.open("C:\\inetpub\\fulltextindex\" )
```

Comment: Looking at `("BAT:", "bas*" ) - `That colon in `BAT:` should be removed. It's the separator between the field name and the term. It's not part of the field name. Not saying this will solve your problem, but it is _a_ problem.

Comment: Can you translate the error message into English?

Comment: Thanks andrewJames, but as you said, 'BAT' did not solve the problem. THe translation is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Understood. You should add the translation to the body of the question, since it directly relates to the problem (information in comments can be overlooked).

Comment: Minor point: I also recommend you edit the code to remove the `:`, even though that is not the solution (it is necessary but not sufficient).

Comment: My ignorance of .Net, but is `dim` equivalent to `Dim`?